# Coverting php array to radio button in HTML?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to create a survey using HTML, PHP, Javascript. So I have my question and answers in a csv file(eventually will be in a SQL server). What I need help is with how can i make my answers radio button(type) so the user can select one of them and I can process it later. The reason i am not hardcoding the questions is because i want to be able to edit them from a file(eventually server).

I have csv file that looks like this:

```
Question 1,Answer1 A,Answer1 B,Answer1 C,Answer1 D
Question 2,Answer2 A,Answer2 B,Answer2 C,Answer2 D
```

Now processing it with php the output looks like this:

```
1. Question 1
Answer1 A
Answer1 B
Answer1 C
Answer1 D
2. Question 2
Answer2 A
Answer2 B
Answer2 C
Answer2 D
```

The code i used for php is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $file = fopen('test.csv','r');
        while(($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
        {
            list($questions[], $optionA[], $optionB[], $optionC[], $optionD[]) = $line;
            //  print_r($line);
        }
        fclose($file);
        $lengthquestion = count($questions);
        $lengthoptionA = count($optionA);
        $lengthoptionB = count($optionB);
        $lengthoptionC = count($optionC);
        $lengthoptionD = count($optionD);

        echo '<ol>';
        for($i=0; $i<$lengthquestion; $i++)
        {
            echo '<li><div>';
            echo $questions[$i] . '<br />';
                echo $optionA[$i] . '<br />';
                echo $optionB[$i] . '<br />';
                echo $optionC[$i] . '<br />';
                echo $optionD[$i] . '<br />';
            echo '</div></li>';
        }
        echo '</ol>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output i want is, of course radio button on the left

```
 A) Answer1 A 
 B) Answer1 B 
 C) Answer1 C 
 D) Answer1 D
```

---

**Update to main question:**

Addition to the main question which is answered by @maytham:

On my top block of code i added this after php.

```
<form name="next" action="submit.php" method="post" id='1'>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My real question is what should be in brackets ([]). Also can I call length question like that. Here is what i think code will look like:

**Here is sumbit.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$file="FILE.csv";
$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("could not open");
for($i=0; $i<$lenghtquestion; $i++)
{ $_SESSION["answer' . $i'"] = $_POST["answer' . $i'"];
  $data.=$_SESSION["answer' . $i'"].",";
  fwrite($fp,$data) or die("could not write"); }
fclose($fp);
```

This doesn't work though

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: Well I know, that each one of those options need to look like                  <input type='radio/>                                                                  <label>$optionA[$i] </label>                                                                                    But dont know how to get there. Any example i saw online it was with a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Radio buttons as group in your `for loop`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $lengthquestion; $i ++)
{
    echo '<li><div>';
    echo $questions[$i] . '<br />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="group' . $i . '" value="' . $optionA[$i] . '">' . $optionA[$i] . '<br />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="group' . $i . '" value="' . $optionB[$i] . '">' . $optionB[$i] . '<br />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="group' . $i . '" value="' . $optionC[$i] . '">' . $optionC[$i] . '<br />';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="group' . $i . '" value="' . $optionD[$i] . '">' . $optionD[$i] . '<br />';
    echo '</div></li>';
}
```

Here how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now i added a sumbit button to my page. That submit button calls a new php file (used action in form to call it). With that sumbit button i want to select the radio option selected for each quesiton. So my new php code looks like this:                                                                        <?php  session_start();                                   $_SESSION['group0']=$_POST['group0'] ; ?>   all the way till lengthquestion. I will do the write this code neatly in anwer. Let me know what i am interpreting wrong.

Comment: OK I am happy it works, but I do not get your message here? could you re-explain in pedagogical way. and maybe show some examples what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, i kind of thought of something so started trying that. But check my answer. I think i might be clear there.

Comment: I will look at it and come with solution, I am out now and will look at it soon I back . Mean while I have edited your question pls approve and then delete the answer, I have added to your main question.

Comment: No worries, I figured it out. Thanks on the first part. Second part was pretty stupid of me because i did not include the <form></form> so it was never calling the second php file. It works and does what i want it to do. Thank You very much for your help.